# pass data from mainView to a subview

Tags: iphone, uiapplicationdelegate

I am building a utility-based application, the data is stored in the `MainViewController`, and  now I know how to pass data to the `FlipsideViewController` (many regards to this thread BTW, [Sending data from Mainview to Flipside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293957/sending-data-from-mainview-to-flipside)). But I am getting the data onto an subview (subclass of `UIView`) that I have added to the flipside view. How can I pass data to this subview? I saw there is already a delegate and protocol set up in the `FlipsideViewController.h`, I am really new to the delegate sort of things. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Updates:

On the main view, I have a couple of text fields for users to input to create an object. All the objects are stored in an array. Namely, my data is created and stored in the `MainViewController`. Now on the flip side, I have a custom UIView subclass which allows me to do my own drawing based on the data in that array. What I need to do here is pass the data that stored in `MainViewController` to this subview. Here is my relevant code:

In the `MainViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    

    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.receiver = data;//this is what I've done.

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

In the `FlipsideViewController.h`

```
@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
    DataModel *receiver; //create a property to receive the data transferred from main view
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DataModel *receiver;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end


@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end
```

In the above code, "data" is an DataModel object declared in the `MainViewController.h` file.

And I want to do my custom drawing in `drawing` class (subclass of UIView), how can I pass data from the `FlipsideViewController`to this subview? Do I need to make use of delegate declared in the `FlipsideViewController.h` file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of data would you want to pass?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a quick look at the template and think you are getting confused with what the delegate is being used for.

The delegate in this template is not transferring data. When you have clicked the done button it calls back to `MainViewController` and asks it to call the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` method so that it can remove the view controller. This seems a bit superflous as the documentation states

```
If you call this method on the modal view controller itself, however, the modal view controller automatically forwards the message to its parent view controller.
```

Therefore you don't really need to call the parent to do this.

In Interface builder you can see that the `FlipsideView.xib` has it's `File's Owner` set to `FlipsideViewController.xib`.

[image]

Now if you right click the `File's Owner` you will see that `view` is connected to `View` this basically means that `view` is the name of the property in `FlipsideViewController` and `View` is the element in Interface Builder.

[image]

Therefore we can access elements in the xib file from `FlipsideViewController` using outlets.

To say draw a label you will need to do a couple of things

First add a property in the .h and synthesize it in the .m like

```
// FlipsideViewController.h
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel; // <----- Added this
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end

// FlipsideViewController.m
@implementation FlipsideViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize testLabel = _testLabel; // <----- Added this

// More methods

- (void)dealloc
{
   [_testLabel release];  // Always do you memory management
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Then back in Interface Builder

1. Add a `UILabel` element to your view
2. `ctrl + drag` from `File's Owner` to the `UILabel` you added
3. Select the label in my example it is `testLabel`

Now these are hooked up correctly. The place where you want to be setting the value of the label is in `viewDidLoad:` which you can now do like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.testLabel.text = @"It Works";  // You would use the data passed in from `MainViewController`
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I am still a little confused here though. My custom view is an instance of flip view when it gets loaded from the nib. I think I should pass data in the initWithCoder() method, right? Rather than calling addSubview method in the flipviewcontroller?

Comment: Sorry I didn't look at the template too long I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can I declare a method like - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish: that's used in the mainviewcontroller in the FlipsideViewControllerDelegate protocol? Then call this new method in the subview to get data?

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way to pass data from one view to another is by directly setting the data in the next view from the original view.

For example;

In your FlipsideViewController.h, declare a 'container' for the data you want to pass. It must be the same class on both sides to work properly, ie. NSArray to NSArray, NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSMutableArray *newData;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *newData; // This allows you to access this object from outside this class.
```

and in FlipsideViewController.m

```
@synthesize newData;
...
[newData release];
```

Now we need to pass the data, so to speak. Let's say the data we want to 'send' is stored in a NSMutableArray called 'results'.

In our MainViewController.m, when we are instantiating our next view controller (in this case FlipsideViewController) we can directly reference the newData mutable array after we initalize the nib.

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
controller.newData = results;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Make sure you are importing your FlipsideViewController in your MainViewController.h file.

If the property is declared in your .h file, you can pretty much reference the contents of the object from anywhere within the view stack!

Hope that helps :D

Comment: I have no problem with sending data from main view to the flipside view like I mentioned in my post. What I want to do is send data to the custom view that's built on top of the flipsideview.