# ASIHTTPRequest issue

Tags: iphone, asp.net, objective-c, http, asihttprequest

I am trying to develop an app which will use this [Cytamobile-Vodafone](http://www.cytamobile-vodafone.com) webservice to login.

I have used HTTP Live Header add-on with Mozilla to get this one:
%3D&HeaderLogin1%24CybeeUserName1%24txtUserName=mavris&HeaderLogin1%24CybeePassword1%24txtPassword=XXXXX&HeaderLogin1%24ibtnLogin.x=20&HeaderLogin1%24ibtnLogin.y=4
HTTP/1.1 302 Found

First I noticed that ibtnLogin.x and ibtnLogin.y have not the same value each time I am trying to login.

Second I wrote this code:

```
-(IBAction) buttonpressed { 

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.cytamobile-vodafone.com/miPortal/HeaderLoginBar.aspx"];

   ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setPostValue:@"xxxxxx" forKey:@"txtUserName"];
   [request setPostValue:@"xxxxxx" forKey:@"txtPassword"];
   [request setPostValue:@"31" forKey:@"ibtnLogin.x"];
   [request setPostValue:@"7" forKey:@"ibtnLogin.y"];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
   [self requestFinished:request];

}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data

    NSString *responseString = [request responseStatusMessage];

    NSLog(@"Output = %@",responseString);
}
```

and I get:

```
  "Output = HTTP/1.1 200 OK" instead of 302 Found or any other error
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of your problems is that your code shouldn't be calling `[self requestFinished:request];` after `[request startAsynchronous];`

The startAsynchronous method starts an asynchronous request, so it will execute the request in a different thread and let you know when it's done.

When the request is complete, ASIHTTPRequest code will call the `requestFinished:` method. It the request fails, it will instead call `requestFailed:`. **You** don't call these methods, the ASIHTTPRequest code will. Check out the [ASIHTTPRequest docs](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#creating_an_asynchronous_request).

This the standard delegate pattern you'll see a lot in Objective-C ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045803/how-does-a-delegate-work-in-objective-c) is one question of many about delegation here on SO).