# iPhone UINavigationController Passing Parameter Back To Main View

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, subview, tablecell

i m new to stackoverflow and this is my first question.
My question is : I have a UINavigationController and have a UITableView inside it. I pass parameter to another view when a cell is clicked in tableview with **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method, and i show the cell information in a label in another view which I called SecondViewController. Inside SecondViewController i have another label and i want to pass it's value to the selected cell's subvalue. As a conclusion i want to pass a value back to navigationcontroller's mainview.

Thanks for all your incoming responses.
Regards,
ae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your secondviewcontroller, the method which was called for popping to the main controller,inside that method pass the value to the mainview property.
For e.g.

One view :---mainview
Second View : secondcontroler

Now Inside secondcontroller:--
-(void)getbacktomainview
{
  mainview *mn ;
  mn.someproperty = yourvalue;
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Hope it helps you.....

Answer (score 1):

would suggest you to use the delegate concept to sorted out you probelm...

Check the useful SO link .

[How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

[How does a delegate work in objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045803/how-does-a-delegate-work-in-objective-c)

[Delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Objective-C_example)