# How do I access a variable in one view controller from another view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

In my UINavtigationController application, I have a user select a value in UITableViewController and once that is done, they are sent back to a previous UITableViewController where that value must be shown. The problem I am anticipating is that once a view is "popped", I am assuming that its viewUnload is called that gets rid of the array making it unaccessible in another view controller.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the new value to previous controller from your didSelectRowIndex function by using anyone of the approaches

**1->** Using `NSUserDefault`.

[iPhone Programming Tutorial – Saving/Retrieving Data Using NSUserDefaults](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)

**2->** Using [Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045803/how-does-a-delegate-work-in-objective-c) concept.

**3->** you could also access the previous **ViewController** from you [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the first view controller via `self.parentViewController`, so it would be best to synthesize an array in the first view, then set it before you call `popViewControllerAnimated:` in the second.  Basically it would look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.parentViewController setNewArray:myArray];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Just make sure you have `NSArray *newArray;` and `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *newArray` specified in the first view's header file and synthesized in the implementation file

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSUserDefaults to achieve the same