# GTL Framework build error with XCode 7 and deployment target 10.10

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-app-engine, xcode7

I'm trying to build GTL project from Google-api-objectivec-client-read-only in XCode 7 with deployment target 10.10. I see the following build errors in GTMOAuth2WindowController.m file

Sending GTMOAuth2WindowController to parameter of incompatible type 'id @ line  [self.webView setResourceLoadDelegate:self];

and
Sending GTMOAuth2WindowController to parameter of incompatible type 'id @ [self.webView setPolicyDelegate:self];

Following is the method block

-

```
 (void)awakeFromNib {
  // load the requested initial sign-in page
  [self.webView setResourceLoadDelegate:self];
  [self.webView setPolicyDelegate:self];

  // the app may prefer some html other than blank white to be displayed
  // before the sign-in web page loads
  NSString *html = self.initialHTMLString;
  if ([html length] > 0) {
    [[self.webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
  }
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved replacing

```
[self.webView setResourceLoadDelegate:self];
[self.webView setPolicyDelegate:self];
```

with

```
[self.webView setResourceLoadDelegate:(id<WebResourceLoadDelegate>)self];
[self.webView setPolicyDelegate:(id<WebPolicyDelegate>)self];
```

I've added a cast (look at [Sending Class to Parameter of Incompatible Type 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>' Warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745838/sending-class-to-parameter-of-incompatible-type-iduiwebviewdelegate-warning))
Bye