# Passing Values Between Master and Detail in UISplitViewController Using Storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have defined the protocol in Customer.h file which is shown below:

```
@class Customer; 
@protocol CustomerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) didSelectCustomer:(Customer *) customer; 

@end

@interface Customer : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name; 
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *occupation; 

@end
```

The MasterViewController (left side) invokes the didSelectCustomer method as shown below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Customer *selectedCustomer = [customers objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [self.delegate didSelectCustomer:selectedCustomer]; 
}
```

Now, I need to tell the DetailViewController (right side) to do something. The DetailViewController complies with the CustomerDelegate protocol.

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate,CustomerDelegate>
{

}

-(void) didSelectCustomer:(Customer *)customer
{
    NSLog(@"sssdasdasdasd");
}
```

The didSelectCustomer method is never invoked. I think I need to set the masterViewController.delegate = self but I am not sure where to set this thing up.

**UPDATE 1:**

I added the instance of MasterViewController inside the DetailViewController but it did not work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    master.delegate = self; 
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

In AppDelegate:

```
  else 
    {
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) self.window.rootViewController; 
        splitViewController.delegate = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];



        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
       // splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;




        DetailViewController *detail =(DetailViewController *) [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];

        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

        MasterViewController *master = (MasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;

        master.delegate = detail; 
    }
```

Comment: Have you fixed the issue? This eats my brain. Please let me know if you've found the fix?

Answer (score 0):

You never explicitly declare yourself as the delegate to the Consumer class.  Merely conforming to it won't cut it.  Declare it in -viewDidLoad by creating an instance of Consumer, possibly like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    Consumer *consumer = [[Consumer alloc]init];
    [consumer setDelegate:self];
}
```

You also don't declare a property for your delegate object in Consumer, so it can never actually be accessed.  Do this first:

```
@class Customer; 
@protocol CustomerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) didSelectCustomer:(Customer *) customer; 

@end

@interface Customer : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name; 
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *occupation; 
@property (weak) id <CustomerDelegate> delegate; //use assign or __unsafe_unretained if targeting <5.0.

@end
```

You can check if your class conforms to your protocol like so:

```
if (![delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CustomerDelegate)]) {
    [NSException raise:@"Delegate Exception"
                format:@"Parameter does not conform to CustomerDelegate protocol at line %d", (int)__LINE__];
}
```

Comment: But then how do I invoke the didSelectCustomer delegate from within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: You're doing that correctly.  You just never assigned a delegate, so it would never have worked.

Comment: My delegate is in the MasterViewController file. So from DetailViewController it should be something _masterViewController.delegate = self; But it is not working.

Comment: You need an instance of MasterViewController.

Comment: I already tried that and it did not work. I am using UISplitViewController. See UPDATE 1

Comment: I pasted the complete code so you can look at it more. http://codepaste.net/c6as3u

Comment: Why have you added the delegate property inside the Customer class? I have the id<CustomerDelegate> inside the MasterViewController.

Comment: Wow, you have some serious misunderstandings as to the format of delegation in ObjC.  See [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) for a tutorial and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045803/how-does-a-delegate-work-in-objective-c) for a related question.

Comment: I have used protocols and delegates before successfully! The only difference is that the Customer class simply have the protocol declaration and then the MasterViewController uses the id<CustomerDelegate> and invokes the didSelectCustomer method.

Comment: I used the confirmsToProtocol and it shows that the DetailViewController DOES conform to the CustomerDelegate.

Comment: Man you were sending me on wild goose chases. Take a look at the edit to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

the split view controller's last object.

this object is return a UI navigation controller.

you know, then you can do yourself.