# iOS Master-Detail app: defining protocol, delegates

Tags: xcode, delegates, master-detail, uistoryboard

In the master-detail application template (using ARC, storyboards) in XCode 4.3.2, I am trying to change (more specifically replace) the detail view when an item in master table view is selected. I am trying to implement delegates/protocols for this.

**What I am confused about is - which class should implement the methods defined in protocol - master or detail?**

Having the detail view implement the protocol method makes sense to me since, I'll be push/popping the view controllers in detail view based on the selection (passed as a string from master via the protocol method).

Here's what I tried

1) Defined the protocol in MasterViewController.h

```
@protocol MasterViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)masterSelectionChanged:(NSString *)selection;
@end
@interface MasterViewController:UIViewContoller
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MasterViewDelegate> delegate
```

2) in MasterViewController.m

```
@synthesize delegate;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [delegate masterSelectionChanged:@"Some string based on indexPath.row"];
}
```

3) in DetailViewController.h

```
#import "MasterViewController.m"
@interface DetailViewController:UINavigationController <MasterViewDelegate>
@end
```

4) in DetailViewController.m

```
#pragma mark - MasterViewDelegate
- (void)masterSelectionChanged:(NSString *)selection
{
    NSLog(@"the selection is: %s", selection);
    // WIll push/pop view over here, may be perform segues based on selection
}
```

In this process, upon selecting the rows in master table, nothing happened. No crash, no display of log, no error while building either. What did I miss over here?

Comment: 1) Are you talking about the iPad or iPhone (the master/detail templates are very different in each one) 2) Have you actually set the delegate property anywhere, or just defined it?

Comment: @jrturton - I am trying this for the iPad one. defining the `delegate` property?? May be that's what I missed. Where should I define the delegate property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate property - at the moment it will be nil so nothing happens when you send messages to it. In the iPad template you can do this as follows, in the `viewDidLoad` of your detail view controller:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
if (self.splitViewController) // Means this won't be called if you use this code on iPhone too.
{
    // According to comments your master controller is embedded in a nav controller
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    // I am assuming it is the root view controller
    MasterViewController *master = (MasterViewController*)nav.rootViewController;
    // Finally set the delegate
    master.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the method defined in protocol is still not being invoked. the delegate is nil when the row is selected.

Comment: what happens if you log master.delegate after the assignment in my code above?: `NSLog(@"master : %@ delegate: %@ self: %@",master,master.delegate,self);`

Comment: it shows - `master: <UINavigationController: xx> delegate: <DetailViewController: xx> self: <DetailViewController: xx>`

Comment: Ah! Your master view controller is embedded in a navigation controller. You'll need to get a pointer to the actual controller itself then - presumably the `rootViewController` of the navigation controller?

Comment: @jrjurton - also I played around with the solution over here which worked fine as well http://stackoverflow.com/q/10019422/206613