# How to pass NSURL from one class to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, nsurl

I'm building an article-reading iOS app. In iPad I'm using split view controller and I want to update detail view controller on tapping different cells in master view controller by passing different URLs.
I am unable to pass `NSURL` form one class to another to **load detail view controller(UITableView)**

**`ysMaster.h`:**

```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *ysURL;
```

**`ysMaster.m:`**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  switch (indexPath.row)
  {
      case 0:
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show1" sender:self];
          _ysURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://you.com/234234"];
      break;

      case 1:
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show2" sender:self];
         _ysURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://goal.com/99099"];
      break;

      case 2:
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show3" sender:self];
          _ysURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gggg.com/99099"];
      break;

      }

   }


     - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSString *)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show1"])
    {

    ysDetail *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
    dest.ysURL=sender;
      }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show2"])
    {

      ysDetail *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
      dest.ysURL=sender;
      [dest setURL:_ysURL];
     }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show3"])
   {

    ysDetail *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
    dest.ysURL=sender;
      }


    }
```

**`ysDetail.h:`**

```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *url;
```

**`ysDetail.m:`**

```
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];
    NSLog(@"uuuuuuuuu%@",_url);   //url prints null
```

Comment: You are assigning the value but not loading the VC. Are you using segue?

Comment: Hi Yogesh,i'm not using any seague,in split view controller master and detail view controller both contain uitableview,detail view is load by url now i want to pass different urls on click on different cells in master view controller.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019422/passing-values-between-master-and-detail-in-uisplitviewcontroller-using-storyboa

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but read Apple's guidelines on naming conventions; class names should always start with a capital letter, not a small one. (:

Comment: thanks @Neeku :),to mention this point.Could you help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get SplitViewController from masterViewController by `self.splitViewController`
Then you can get detailViewController as

```
  DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController*)self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];

  detailViewController.url = yourURL;
```

Comment: @thanks Suhail,i'm doing the same in my code please look again.But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `ysDetail` Object, then creating a method with your `ysDetail` class that is a getter for the `Url`.

```
-(void)getUrl:(NSURL)url;
```

and to create an object:

```
@Property ysDetail *detailClass;
```