# Is there a way to send an object via Delegates in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a scenario, where I am waiting for a uiwebview to get fully loaded and then a delegate called from finishedWebViewLoading once completed. However, I want to return that webView when finished loading as an object which is a private object to another Class. Is there anyway to do that through delegates? I don't want to have that uiwebview as a public property, hence I have utilized it under my main file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure you can do it like this .. in .h

```
@protocol yourClassProtocal <NSObject>

- (void) loadingFinsihForWebView:(UIWebView*)wv;

@end
```

and in the webView Delegate `webViewDidFinishLoad`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [delegate loadingFinsihForWebView:webView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: YES. 
However, I believe you might need to read up on how delegates work and how to create them, this post might get you on the right path getting there: [How does a delegate work in objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045803/how-does-a-delegate-work-in-objective-c)

Also, have a look at this article: http://blog.shoguniphicus.com/2011/10/17/writing-custom-delegate-in-objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 if([self.theDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(loadData:)]) {
        [self.theDelegate performSelector:@selector(loadData:) withObject:theObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but you cannot return any value from `(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView`, nor can you change the delegate signature.

On the other hand, if you mean that you are going to call another custom delegate method from `webViewDidFinishLoad`, and that you want that it returns the `webView`, then this is definitely possible. Simply call that custom delegate method and pass the `webView` to it, then make the custom delegate method return it.

This assumes you are in charge of the definition of the custom delegate method signature, e.g.:

```
@protocol CustomDelegateProtocol
    - (UIWebView*)myCustomDelegateMethod:(UIWebView*)view;
@end
```