# What's Javascript equivalent to iOS's delegate function?

Tags: javascript, ios

```
- (void)shootMissile {

  //Send missile to delegate for storage
  if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(shootMissile)]) {
     [delegate performSelector:@selector(shootMissile)];
   }
}
```

delegate function means it's delegate to another function in a different file.

I am not sure I run into something like that in javascript.

Comment: This is the second question from you I have seen about porting Objective-C to Javascript. You are in for a world of pain if you approach this way because your code is depending on Objective-C idioms and Cocoa framework objects. Javascript is sufficiently different enough where you need to step back and take a look at the whole design with Javascript in mind.

Answer (score 2):

As per the second answer on this question [How does a delegate work in objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045803/how-does-a-delegate-work-in-objective-c):

> Delegates are a design pattern; there is no special syntax or language support.

That pattern certainly can be used in Javascript, where functions are first-class objects, and thus can be passed to other functions as arguments.

To rewrite your example in JS:

```
function shootMissile(selector) {
     if (selector.respondsTo(shootMissile)) {
         selector.perform(shootMissile);
     }
   }
}
```

Where presumably "selector" is an object that has two function properties (ie. methods) called "respondsTo" and "perform".

A more natural-looking (or at least more functional) version of the above would be:

```
function shootMissile(canShootMissile, fireMissile, missile) {
     if (canShootMissile(missile)) {
         fireMissile(missile);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be something like an *anonymous function*. Also could be referred to as a *callback function* I suppose.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

First a correction of the following assumption:

"delegate function means it's delegate to another function in a different file."

1) forget the "file" thing, it's all about context (a class instance for example)

2) It does not delegate to other function : function is delegated to another context (in Javascript, access the context with "this" keyword)

So in javascript, given the following function:

```
var shootMissile = function () {
    this.missiles --;
};
```

We may delegate it to a bunch of different contexts (= objects), for example a boat:

```
var Boat = function () {
    this.missiles = 10 ;
},
boatInstance = new Boat () ;
```

Or a plane:

```
var Plane = function () {
    this.missiles = 5 ;
},
planeInstance = new Plane () ;
```

Finally the working example:

```
// planeInstance will have 4 missiles after call of delegated function
shootMissile.apply (planeInstance);

// boatInstance will have 9 missiles after call of delegated function
shootMissile.apply (boatInstance);
```

Hope this short explanation is sufficient for you.